# Updating a partial via Ajax with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, voting

I am trying to update a rails partial while using Ajax and having some trouble.  Basically I have a Post with a Karma attribute.  Users can vote up and vote down to take and remove Karma from the post.  I would like to allow the user to asynchronously update the post value using Ajax and im running into a NilClass error that im hoping you can help me with.
The error im getting is undefined method `karma' for nil:NilClass (in my _karma_value.erb file), and my files look like below.  Im totally stuck!

posts_controller.rb

```
   def add_karma
     # Save the page that the request came from
     session[:initial_page] ||= request.referer

     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @post.karma = @post.karma + 1
     @post.update_attributes(params[:post])

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to session[:initial_page] }  #redirect back to requesting page
       format.json { head :no_content }
       format.js {}
     end   
   end
```

add_karma.js.erb

```
   $('#add_karma').html(
     "<%= escape_javascript(render('_karma_value', post: @post)) %>");
```

index.html.erb

```
...
<b>Karma:</b> 
        <%= render(:partial => 'karma_value', :locals => {:post => @post}) %>  <br>
...
```

_karma_value.erb

```
<% if !(post.karma.nil?) %>
    <%= post.karma %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **@post** will be nil in the partial.

Because, while rendering partial, you have mentioned the local variable **post** as **@post**. But using **@post** in partial.

Just use **post** in that partial.

in `_karma_value.html.erb`

```
<% if !(post.karma.nil?) %>
  <%= post.karma %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that before, and tried it again after your comment - but I get the same error message: undefined method `karma' for nil:NilClass

Comment: once can you check by modifying the content of the **add_karma.js.erb** file like `$('#add_karma').html("<%= render(:partial => 'karma_value', :locals => {:post => @post}) %>")`.

Comment: Ok I did this and it worked - (I no longer am receiving the undefined method error) I think the problem was I still had the underscore in front of karma_value - but now that its rendering properly - I cannot get the partial to refresh (i.e. the value stays the same until I refresh the entire page).  

Any Ideas?

Comment: U didnt mentioned the DOM element having id as **add_karma** in **index.html.erb**. If you are updating the proper element in the **.js.erb** file, then surely it will reflect.

Comment: OMG this totally worked!  I was completely misunderstanding the javascript and thought that the $('#add_karma').html was referring to the controller action it was tied to and not the DOM element.  Adding the add_karma div to the DOM totally solved the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Hrmmm... interestingly enough - this always updates the first post element in the index file (not the same element that I click).  Will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

you pass `:locals => {:post => @post}` so you should use `post` instead of `@post` inside _karma_value.erb partial

Comment: I tried that before, and tried it again after your comment - but I get the same error message: undefined method `karma' for nil:NilClass - nothing else changes.

Comment: then `@post` is nil at index.html.erb. Check index action.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the same exact `render :partial =>` command in both `add_karma.js.erb` and `index.html.erb`? It seems that you are not rendering correctly the partial in the `add_karma.js.erb`.